# How do I fix "Cannot read property of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

How can I fix this error? I have tried, but still cannot make it.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
App
C:/Users/Bogosyna/Desktop/IT job projects/roro-facebook/src/App.js:11
   8 | import {useStateValue} from "./StateProvider";
   9 | 
  10 | function App() {
> 11 |   const [{ user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  12 | 
  13 |   return (
  14 |     <div className="app">
```

And here is the implementation of useStateValue()

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children}) => (
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
);

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried providing `initialState` with the `user` object?

```
initialState = {
  user: {},
}
```

And then passing it to `useReducer(reducer, initialState)`.

If this is not something you can do, then do not destructure the user so early, have something like this:

```
const [values, dispatch] = useStateValue();

console.log(values.user) // See when the user is available
```

or provide user with initial empty object, like this:

```
const [{user} = {}, dispatch] = useStateValue();
```